# Custom helper with handlebars-loader

Tags: helper, webpack-4, webpack-handlebars-loader

I'm using this [handlebars-loader](https://github.com/pcardune/handlebars-loader) for webpack 4. Now I wanted to use a custom helper, but i only get this error

> ERROR in Template execution failed: TypeError: __default(...).call is not a function
>
> ERROR in   TypeError: __default(...).call is not a function

this is my webpack.config

```
//handlebars-loader
{
  test: /\.(hbs)$/,
  loader: "handlebars-loader",
  options: {
    helperDirs: [path.join(__dirname, './src/hbs/helpers')],
    partialDirs: [path.join(__dirname, './src/hbs/partials')]
  },
}
```

and this is my simple helper

```
const Handlebars = require('handlebars');
Handlebars.registerHelper('repeat', function(n) {
  console.log(n);
});
```

and how I use it

```
{{#repeat 10}}
    <span> repeat</span>
{{/repeat}}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've been wrestling with this for a little while now, I think its a bug with the loader in webpack 4. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: looking at using this approach - could you tell me nam of the helper file ? Or does it matter as you seem to reference the whole helpers directory? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution. I have to export the helper as a module, then it works.

```
//repeat.js
module.exports = function(times, options) {
    console.log(times);
};
```

Comment: How do I use "Handlebars" variable within this file. It gives me an error when I try to import it.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, Gregor! This has been frustrating me all day!

I had a simple function in a helper file, checkActive.js :

```
const Handlebars = require("handlebars")

Handlebars.registerHelper("checkActive", function (pageName, linkedPageName) {
  return pageName === linkedPageName ? "active" : ""
})
```

This would not work and gave me this error:

```
ERROR in Template execution failed: TypeError: __default(...).call is not a function

ERROR in   TypeError: __default(...).call is not a function
```

I found your solution and tried it. Lo-and-behold it worked! This is what I am now using instead:

```
module.exports = function (pagename, linkedPageName) {
  return pagename === linkedPageName ? "active" : ""
  console.log(pagename)
};
```

In order for this to work, you need to have the function saved in a file with the same name as the handlebars helper function you are calling, ie. in my case: checkActive.js